# bash ftp change directory on remote server

Tags: ftp, shell

I have a shell script that FTPs some non-sensitive data to a remote server. However, I would like to set the remote path rather than just use the remote FTP user's default path. I have searched for ages but can't find any way of doing this which seems crazy.

Here's a sample of a relevant part of my script;

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd "$path" # local path
cp some.log "$stamp"_some.log
ftp -n -p $ftp_host <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $ftp_user
quote PASS $ftp_pass
binary
put "$stamp"_some.log
quit
END_SCRIPT
```

Is there really no way to change the remote path to upload to?

Comment: use `cd` (change directory) command before `put`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reading the [ftp man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ftp) I see two ways:

```
cd /path/to/dir
put "$stamp"_some.log
```

Or:

```
put "$stamp"_some.log /path/to/dir/"$stamp"_some.log
```

Further, you can just skip the copy command and directly use:

```
put some.log /path/to/dir/"$stamp"_some.log
```

Comment: I did check the man page and also before posting this question I tried cd /path before 'put' but it threw an error which seemed as though it was trying to change to a directory on the local machine. I also tried adding the remote path at the end of the put command but that failed. I didn't do what you did though which was also add the file name to the end. I will give your suggestions a go again now that I know they should work. I'll be back to accept your answer.